# Is it possible to bevel (or round) a bezier vector handle?

Tags: bezier-curves, text-object

I'm trying to match bezier curves to letters (trace them) so that I can make a neon sign, however the font that I'm trying to use has multiple sharp edges that can't exist (because there are no sharp edges on neon signs). For now, when I encounter a sharp edge, I just do this: [image]

I round them out with simple "Aligned" handle types. However, this method is slow and imprecise, and because I have to eyeball it, it would likely be noticeably different for every letter. Is there any method I can use to round out a "Vector" handle type? They match the sharp corners of edges very well, but I can't have the corners remain sharp.

[image]

Comment: An unpreferred solution would be subdividing the corner multiple times and adjusting the curve until it best fitted your text.

Comment: How was the text generated? If it's generated as an image just trace it in inkscape or illustrator as a path and save it as SVG, then import the SVGs into blender and you'll have the perfect curves that match your letters.

Comment: @cegaton The text is a text object with the Futura Extra Black Condensed font imported in. I think I may have fixed my problem by adding depth to the curve, and simply fitting the edge of the tube to the edge of the letter. I noticed that while neon sign tubes don't ever bend sharply at 90 degrees, the inside edge of the tube can get close to that effect: http://i.cubeupload.com/wUHwaa.png

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Bevel on a curve. You can, however, bevel a mesh and convert it to a curve.

I used a cube to create this shape, deleted all but one edge loop, and used Alt+C in Object mode to convert to a curve.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]